# Attempting to merge several CSV files, program hangs on seemingly arbitrary file

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a bunch of CSV files with common columns but different rows. I want to merge them all into one CSV file. Here is the script I wrote to do that

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("./data")
fout = open("merged.csv", "a")
lout = open("merger_log", "a")
for fname in glob.glob("*.csv*"):
        with open(fname) as f:
                # exclude header for all but the first csv file.
                if os.stat("merged.csv").st_size > 0:
                        next(f)
                fout.writelines(f)
        log = "Appended %s \n" % fname
        print(log)
        lout.write(log)

fout.close()
lout.close()
```

When I run this script, it successfully appends the first few files but gets stuck on one file every time. And by stuck it seems to be adding bits from said file to the output file without moving on to the next file. There's nothing special about the file it stops on, it's about the same size as the rest of them and is not malformed. In fact, I removed that file from the data set and the program hung on a different file. Not sure what is wrong with this script.

If anyone has a better way to merge a bunch of CSV files, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

EDIT: I should mention this script works perfectly fine with just two files.

Comment: It looks that your `'merged.csv'` is one of `glob.glob("*.csv*")`

Comment: @taras nailed it!